# maven dependency:copy-dependencies is renaming incorrectly a .so dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies

While running maven goal dependency:copy-dependencies is can see my file 'a.so' being renamed 'a.jar', however the type property has been set to ensure maven is aware of the dependency type. How can I force the goal dependency:copy-dependencies to create my dependency 'a' with the appropriate extension?

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mystuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>so</type>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
...
```

Comment: Why are you using `copy-depenencies` in your Maven build? Can you explain more detail what kind of problem you have and what you done so far? BTW: A full pom file would help...

Comment: I am using it so my dependencies can be included next to my jar during delivery to environments.

Comment: My issue got resolved - it wasn't related to maven at all - no issues with maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue got resolved - it wasn't related to maven at all - no issues with maven here.